# How to group javascript files into its typescript file in webstorm on mac osx

Tags: typescript, webstorm

On Windows, WebStorm display javascript files under the typescript files which they generated from in the `Project` window. 
But on mac osx, the `Project` window display javascript files besides typescript files.

How to get WebStorm on OSX to display the generated javascript as it does on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping relations are established when running the compiler; this behavior is not OS-specific. Please make sure to set your Project tool window scope to 'Project' - grouping doesn't works when using other scopes ('Project Files', 'Problems', etc.) - see [WEB-15708](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15708)

Answer (score 0):

`File` - `Settings` - `Typescript` - Enable `Typescript Compiler`